Sam decoder model is returning the error:Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined, tried to load the encoder image embeddings .txt file
I'm using ONNX react-native-runtime environment and I have the encoder image_embeddings in a text file in my root project directory. When I try to read the text file with encoder image embeddings, the react-native can able to read the file. But if I pass the data to the same decoder model its not even reading the image_embeddings from the text file.
Its returning this error:
Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined.

Here is my code please check it.
const decoderModelPath = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/vit_h_decoder.onnx`;

  console.log('Decoder model path is loading....');

  await RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl: Image.resolveAssetSource(
      require('./models/vit_h_decoder.onnx'),
    ).uri,
    toFile: decoderModelPath,
  }).promise;

  console.log('Decoder model is started processing....');

  const decoderSession = await ort.InferenceSession.create(
    'file://' + decoderModelPath,
  );

  console.log('Decoder model is loaded....');

  const txtFile = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/react-embeddings.txt`;

  await RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl: Image.resolveAssetSource(require('./react-embeddings.txt'))
      .uri,
    toFile: txtFile,
  }).promise;

  console.log('Embeddings are loading...Please wait....');

  const fileEmbeddings = await FileSystem.readFile(txtFile);

  console.log('Embeddings are going to parse....');

  const parseDataFile = JSON.parse(fileEmbeddings);

  console.log(Object.keys(parseDataFile));
  console.log('Embeddings are Parsed successfully....');

  console.log('Feed is going to load....');

  const feed = {
    image_embeddings: parseDataFile,
    point_coords: new ort.Tensor(
      new Float32Array([10, 10, 0, 0]),
      [1, 2, 2],
    ),
    point_labels: new ort.Tensor(new Float32Array([0, -1]), [1, 2]),
    mask_input: new ort.Tensor(
      new Float32Array(256 * 256),
      [1, 1, 256, 256],
    ),
    has_mask_input: new ort.Tensor(new Float32Array([0]), [1]),
    orig_im_size: new ort.Tensor(new Float32Array([684, 1024]), [2]),
  };

  console.log('Feed is loaded...');
  const finalData = await decoderSession.run(feed);

  const filePath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/example.txt`;

  await RNFS.writeFile(
    filePath,
    JSON.stringify(finalData.masks.data),
    'utf8',
  );

  await Share.open({
    title: 'Share file',
    url: `file://${filePath}`,
  });

  console.log('Done with the decoder model');

I tried to load the txt file, its not working so i need some help from the community to load the encoder embeddings in the decoder of sam models
